# ValueError: Either 'hosts' or 'cloud_id' must be specified ; while running elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, yelp

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers 

es = Elasticsearch()
```

while running the above code facing the below error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [15], in <cell line: 6>()
      1 #Import Elascticsearch and helpers from  elasticsearch
      3 from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers 
----> 6 es = Elasticsearch()

File /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/_sync/client/__init__.py:191, in Elasticsearch.__init__(self, hosts, cloud_id, api_key, basic_auth, bearer_auth, opaque_id, headers, connections_per_node, http_compress, verify_certs, ca_certs, client_cert, client_key, ssl_assert_hostname, ssl_assert_fingerprint, ssl_version, ssl_context, ssl_show_warn, transport_class, request_timeout, node_class, node_pool_class, randomize_nodes_in_pool, node_selector_class, dead_node_backoff_factor, max_dead_node_backoff, serializer, serializers, default_mimetype, max_retries, retry_on_status, retry_on_timeout, sniff_on_start, sniff_before_requests, sniff_on_node_failure, sniff_timeout, min_delay_between_sniffing, sniffed_node_callback, meta_header, timeout, randomize_hosts, host_info_callback, sniffer_timeout, sniff_on_connection_fail, http_auth, maxsize, _transport)
    128 def __init__(
    129     self,
    130     hosts: t.Optional[_TYPE_HOSTS] = None,
   (...)
    188     _transport: t.Optional[Transport] = None,
    189 ) -> None:
    190     if hosts is None and cloud_id is None and _transport is None:
--> 191         raise ValueError("Either 'hosts' or 'cloud_id' must be specified")
    193     if timeout is not DEFAULT:
    194         if request_timeout is not DEFAULT:

ValueError: Either 'hosts' or 'cloud_id' must be specified
```

The elastic server is up and running able to host.
Unable to execute my existing script

Answer (score 3):

please see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/connecting.html. you need to use something like;

```
es = Elasticsearch(
    "https://localhost:9200",
    ca_certs="/path/to/http_ca.crt",
    basic_auth=("elastic", ELASTIC_PASSWORD)
)
```